# Subtracting rows from each other in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have what I assume is a fairly simple issue but just can't get the code correct for it to work. This is a simplified version of my dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Jan', 'Apples', 10], ['Feb', 'Apples', 14], 
                   ['Jan', 'Oranges', 24], ['Feb', 'Oranges', 18]],
                    columns = ['Month', 'Fruit', 'Sales'])

  Month    Fruit  Sales
0   Jan   Apples     10
1   Feb   Apples     14
2   Jan  Oranges     24
3   Feb  Oranges     18
```

I then wish to calculate two new rows which are the sales for Febraury minus the sales for January grouped by type of fruit. I have seen the diff function which would obviously work with this simplified dataframe. But my real dataframe is much bigger and the number of periods between the values I want to subtract is not constant. So I am looking for something with loc and groupby (I assume).

Greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: `the number of periods between the values I want to subtract is not constant`, could you share a sample when this takes place? ANd also share the expected output

Answer (score 0):

IICU, this is what you need. As the number of months increase, this will give the difference in sales between two months.

```
df['dif']= df.groupby(['Fruit'])['Sales'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Month   Fruit   Sales   dif
0   Jan     Apples      10  0
1   Feb     Apples      14  4
2   Jan     Oranges     24  0
3   Feb     Oranges     18  -6
```

OR

You can use the custom function below

```
def func(mon1,mon2,fruit):
    g = df.groupby(['Fruit'])
    f = g.get_group(fruit)
    a = f.loc[f.Month == mon1, 'Sales'].iloc[0]
    b = f.loc[f.Month == mon2, 'Sales'].iloc[0]
    return b-a
```

Call the function as , for example `func('Jan', 'Feb', 'Oranges')` & you will get the difference in sales between the months for the respective fruit.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you're subtracting the sales in `Feb` from `Jan`, one option is to define the `Month` column as a `pd.Categorical`, specifying an ordering fore the `categories`, and take the `diff` of the two first `Sales` values, which will also work with additional months:

```
   Month    Fruit  Sales
0   Jan   Apples     10
2   Apr   Apples     21
3   Feb   Apples     14
4   Apr   Apples     21
5   Jan  Oranges     24
6   Feb  Oranges     18
```

---

```
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df.Month.tolist(), categories=['Jan', 'Feb'])
df.sort_values('Month', inplace=True)
df.groupby('Fruit').Sales.apply(lambda x: x.head(2).diff().iloc[1])

Fruit
Apples     4.0
Oranges   -6.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
​
```